# Ubuntu 18.04 problem

Tags: upgrade

I recently upgraded my Toshiba Satellite laptop to Ubuntu 18.04; it had happily been running an earlier version while connected to a larger screen.
After the update I got the log-in screen and my old password was accepted. However, the screen then went blank with only an active cursor showing.
After much trial and error I found that if I disconnect the external display then I get my desktop back with old data files intact.
Is there any way I can use my external display with 18.04; if not how do I revert to my previous version of Ubuntu?
Regards.

Comment: Please edit the topic title to reflect your actual question.